# loop issue where I want to exclude last 3

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey I have this wordpress setup, and I'm not really a PHP developer. What I want to achieve is for the loop to exclude the last 3 posts created. Is there a way to go about doing this?

```
            <div class="grid">

                <?php
                // Start the loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'square' ); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
                // End the loop.
                endwhile; ?>

            </div><!-- .grid -->

            <?php the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size' => 2, 'prev_text' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>', 'next_text' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>' ) );

            // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        else :
            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
        endif;
        ?>
```

Comment: It's probably more appropriate to do this as a custom query...

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable that counts the total posts ($count = [total posts]) and then iterate through the posts using a for loop setting your max iteration for $count-3:

```
for($i=0; $i<($count-3); $i++){
    do something;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The post count for a "standard" loop like this is stored in the global `$wp_query`. To access it, you can use `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->post_count`.

```
<?php
// Get the post count and set a counter variable
$count = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->post_count; $i = 0;
while ( have_posts() && $i < $count - 3 ) : the_post(); ?>

    <!-- Post content loop -->

<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
```

Keep in mind that this will only work if you have more than 3 posts...